# Convert epoch to date in sqlplus / Oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime, date, sqlplus, epoch

I have the following table:

```
SQL> desc recording
 Name                 Null?    Type
 -------------------- -------- ------
 CAPTUREID            NOT NULL NUMBER(9)
 STARTDATE            NOT NULL DATE
 ENDDATE                       DATE
 STATE                         NUMBER(1)
 ESTIMATEDENDTIME              NUMBER(13)
```

Here's a single line for this table:

```
SQL> select * from recording where CAPTUREID=14760457;

 CAPTUREID STARTDATE           ENDDATE             STATE ESTIMATEDENDTIME
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ----- ----------------
  14760457 29/09/2010 08:50:01 29/09/2010 09:52:04     0    1285746720000
```

I'm pretty sure that this has been asked so many times before, but all the solutions I've found so far didn't really work, so... How do I convert `ESTIMATEDENDTIME` from its original epoch form to a `DD/MM/YYY  HH:MI:SS` format in a single query in SQLPLUS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Oracle, adding X to a DATE will return you a DATE X days later.

If ESTIMATEDENDTIME is milliseconds since Epoch then you could do

```
DATE '1970-01-01' + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000) * ESTIMATEDENDTIME
```

and then use to_char to achieve the correct format of the resulting date. e.g:

```
SELECT 
  captureid
, startdate
, enddate
, state
, estimatedendtime
, DATE '1970-01-01' + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000) * estimatedendtime AS estimatedenddate
FROM recording
```

Comment: Damn! That's faster and easier than other solutions I was trying! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

```
select ((timestamp_coloum_name - to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (86400)) from any_table;
```