# How to convert Epoch time to date?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, unix-timestamp

Hi I have a column with number datatype 
the data like  **1310112000** this is a date, but I don't know how to make it in an understandable format:
ex: 10-mar-2013 12:00:00 pm

Can any one please help me.

Comment: Can you accept the answer? It helps the other with same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert epoch to date in sqlplus / Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820179/convert-epoch-to-date-in-sqlplus-oracle)

Comment: Yes, its working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is EPOCH time: number of seconds since Epoch(1970-01-01). Use this:

```
SELECT CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 ) * '1310112003' AS TIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL;
```

Result:

```
08-JUL-11 08.00.03.000000000 AM
```

Answer (score 9):

Please try

```
select from_unixtime(floor(EPOCH_TIMESTAMP/1000)) from table;
```

This will give the result like E.g: 2018-03-22 07:10:45
PFB refence from [MYSQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: Just remove the "/1000" if you dont have millisecs, works fine for me

Answer (score 4):

In Microsoft SQL Server, the previous answers did not work for me.  But the following does work.

```
SELECT created_time AS created_time_raw, 
dateadd( second, created_time, CAST( '1970-01-01' as datetime ) ) AS created_time_dt 
FROM person
```

`person` is a database table, and `created_time` is an integer field whose value is a number of seconds since epoch.

There may be other ways to do the `datetime` arithmetic.  But this is the first thing that worked.  I do not know if it is MSSQL specific.