# Convert numeric to datetime

Tags: sql-server, sailpoint

I'm querying a SQL Server table that has this column:

```
dateCreated(numeric(19, 0), null)
```

It appears this is UNIX epoch time. I want to select everything from the table and convert the `dateCreated` column to something appropriate for a report extract. I've tried the following via some other posts I found:

[How to convert Epoch time to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289218/how-to-convert-epoch-time-to-date)

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(S, t.dateCreated, CAST('1970-01-01' as datetime)), 
    t.user, t.machine  
FROM
    table t
```

Any variant of this produces an error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

How can I convert this column to `datetime` format?

Comment: Please show some sample data.

Comment: These are a few values from the dateCreated column - the data from the other columns is not relevant:

1611289394250
1607951513597
1607168238692

Comment: [edit] and additional information directly into the question.

Answer (score 1):

That happen because for at least one row in t, `t.dateCreated` is bigger than 2147483647.

2147483647 is the max value of int data type in SQL Server.

2147483647 is 2038-01-19 03:14:07 in EPOCH time.

If `t.dateCreated` is really EPOCH time and `t.dateCreated` has values higher than 2038-01-19 03:14:07, that query is not going to work.

Maybe you should check:

- If `t.dateCreated` is really EPOCH time.
- The rows where `t.dateCreated` > 2147483647, just in case of some outliers.

Another thing to check, is if the EPOCH time is expressed in milliseconds.

In that case, the query should be

```
SELECT 
DATEADD(S, t.dateCreated / 1000, CAST('1970-01-01' as datetime)), 
    t.user, t.machine   
FROM
    table t
```

But you are going to miss the milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you! I already put some of the values into a website to convert epoch time and it verified so I was absolutely certain it was epoch time but it seems it is in fact in milliseconds. Adding the /1000 did the trick.