# How do I convert data that is in text to date?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I convert data that is in text to date in MySQL?

The data I have is like this

```
20210422
20210423
```

I want the data in this format

```
2021-04-22
```

Comment: You have to convert epoch time in seconds to date
you should check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289218/how-to-convert-epoch-time-to-date

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what kind of database you are using, and a quick google search should turn up the proper conversion function for your DBMS. For example, MS SQL date conversion is done via CAST and CONVERT functions: [CAST and CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I am using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I guess here there is some misunderstanding between date-storage and date-representation, but could you please try(for MS SQL Server)

```
 DECLARE @InDate1 DATE='20210422';
 SELECT  @InDate1 AS ORIGG,CONVERT(DATE,@InDate1,120)AS CONV;
```

Comment: There is column with more than 1000 rows, Can't declare for every row

Comment: Situation is even worse. You use MySql and I am not sure, if the above code runs in it